# How to implement Hazelcast PortableFactory for Portable enum

Tags: java, serialization, enums, hazelcast

I have a Java enum **A** that I want to serialize with Hazelcast Portable interface.

To implement the PortableFactory associated with **A** I need to call an empty constructor to create an empty instance of **A**, but that is not possible when it comes to enum in Java.

What's the best way to implement a PortableFactory to serialize enum?

Here an example of what I'd like to achive:

```
public class MyPortableFactory implements PortableFactory {

    @Override
    public Portable create( int classId ) {
        if (Foo.ID == classId) {
            return new Foo(); //This is how you return normal class
        } else if(MyEnum.ID == classId) {
            return ???; //What should I return for the enum?
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

*I have tried a workoround using a map to change the ids:*

```
public enum MyEnum implements Portable { 

    Value1("1", "1", PortableIds.one),
    Value2("2", "2", PortableIds.two),
    Invalid("0", "0", PortableIds.InvalidID);


    private String first;
    private String second;
    private Integer portableId;

    public static final Map<Integer, MyEnum> mapPortableIdValues = new HashMap<>() {{
        for (MyEnum myEnum : MyEnum.values()) {
            put(myEnum.getPortableId(), myEnum);
        }
    }};

    @Override
    public int getFactoryId() {
        return MyPortableFactory.FACTORY_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public int getClassId() {
        return portableId;
    }
```

```
public class MyPortableFactory implements PortableFactory {

    public static final int FACTORY_ID = 2;

    @Override
    public Portable create(int classId) {
        if(mapPortableIdValues.containsKey(classId)){
            return mapPortableIdValues.get(classId);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
public interface PortableIds {

    Integer one = 100;
    Integer two = 101;
    Integer InvalidID = 106;
}
```

But when I run my application I get the following exception:

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Wrong Portable type! Generic portable types are not supported! Expected class-id: 100, Actual class-id: 106
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.portable.DefaultPortableWriter.checkPortableAttributes(DefaultPortableWriter.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.portable.DefaultPortableWriter.writePortable(DefaultPortableWriter.java:147)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this use case is not a good fit for the design of the Portable serialization. The mechanism of Portable serialization instantiates an instance of a class and fills the fields with `readPortable` method at runtime. This is not really possible with enums.

I would suggest using a wrapper class to carry simply an integer enum tag or the name of the enum member as a string with Portable serialization.

Comment: Thanks, following your suggestion I decided to simply serialize a String identifier instead of the enum end get the correct enum value in the readPortable from the id.